# SSIS job schedule

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Lets say Job "Alphabet" does tasks A-Z. In 15min mark the job will be in task M or in other words it will not complete in 15 min. . During my tests, I ran without a schedule or a one time run, it runs and completes successfully. Then I ran with a scheduler with " Everyday: every 15m". Here with a scheduler, I see the job never hits Z or never completes. Is the SQL agent stopping the instance and starting a new one ?

Comment: Are you implying sql agent is the job scheduler?

Comment: Hmm I dont think i used the word job agent. But.. yes.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question then. It has only the SSIS tag and SSIS has no scheduler built into it. Therefore, I assume that you are using an external scheduler and unless specified, people generally are using SQL Agent for SSIS. So, now that you understand my assumptions, it is unclear to me precisely what you are asking. Is the question "will sql agent start the next iteration of the job" or is it "does sql agent support trend analysis to determine whether a job is inside/outside tolerance for a run", etc

Comment: I see. My apologies. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy one to test for yourself. In the following, I create a SQL Agent Job with a single step which creates a table in tempdb if it doesn't exist.

It then waits 90 seconds before inserting the current timestamp. But, it is scheduled to run every minute.

```
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @jobId binary(16)
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Overlapping Execution'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
,   @notify_level_email = 2
,   @notify_level_netsend = 2
,   @notify_level_page = 2
,   @delete_level = 0
,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
,   @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
SELECT
    @jobId
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'Overlapping Execution'
,   @server_name = N'localhost\DEV2014'
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Overlapping Execution'
,   @step_name = N'Insert into table'
,   @step_id = 1
,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
,   @on_success_action = 1
,   @on_fail_action = 2
,   @retry_attempts = 0
,   @retry_interval = 0
,   @os_run_priority = 0
,   @subsystem = N'TSQL'
,   @command = N'USE tempdb
GO
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables AS T WHERE T.name = ''WatchMe''
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Watchme
    (
        StartTime datetime NOT NULL
    );
END
GO

-- wait for 90 seconds to ensure overlap
WAITFOR DELAY ''00:01:30'';

-- Add a row so we can demonstrate activity
INSERT INTO
    dbo.Watchme
(
    StartTime
)
VALUES
    (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
'
,   @database_name = N'tempdb'
,   @flags = 0
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job
    @job_name = N'Overlapping Execution'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @start_step_id = 1
,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
,   @notify_level_email = 2
,   @notify_level_netsend = 2
,   @notify_level_page = 2
,   @delete_level = 0
,   @description = N''
,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
,   @notify_email_operator_name = N''
,   @notify_netsend_operator_name = N''
,   @notify_page_operator_name = N''
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @schedule_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule
    @job_name = N'Overlapping Execution'
,   @name = N'EveryMinute'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @freq_type = 4
,   @freq_interval = 1
,   @freq_subday_type = 4
,   @freq_subday_interval = 1
,   @freq_relative_interval = 0
,   @freq_recurrence_factor = 1
,   @active_start_date = 20141023
,   @active_end_date = 99991231
,   @active_start_time = 0
,   @active_end_time = 235959
,   @schedule_id = @schedule_id OUTPUT
SELECT
    @schedule_id
GO
```

So, what happens? SQL Agent won't start the job if it's already running. If you try to manually run it

> Start failed for Job 'Overlapping Execution'. 
>   Request to run job Overlapping Execution (from User pity\dafool) refused because the job is already running from a request by User mr\T. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22022)

Instead, the agent will skip the missed starts until it's able to actually start. Here you can see the history. It started at 4:50. Missed the start at 4:51 as it was already running but caught the 4:52 window.

[image]

If I query my watchme table

```
SELECT
    WM.*
FROM
    dbo.WatchMe AS WM 
ORDER BY
    1
```

I can see that yes, my insert times are approximately 90 seconds after the job would have started.

```
StartTime
2014-10-23 16:51:30.277
2014-10-23 16:53:30.767
2014-10-23 16:55:30.790
2014-10-23 16:57:30.793
2014-10-23 16:59:30.870
```

### Directly answering the question

No, the Agent won't stop a currently executing job to start a new instance of it.

Turn on logging within your packages (I favor SQL Server and logging OnPre/PostExecute, OnError, OnTaskFailed) and you should be able to divine where it's at in the process along with any failure information.

Answer (score 0):

Add a AA step where you check if the job is already running.

```
SELECT sj.name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
    AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
    AND name = 'Alphabet'
```

If so, skip steps A-Z.

Comment: I see where this is going. I simply wanted a Yes/No answer. But, this is helpful too. I tested the thing. It does not finish, ever. But wanted to be sure.